# python to php interface

Tags: python, php, raspberry-pi, gpio

im working on a application to run on a raspberry pi that uses a php based page to control relays connected via GPIO outputs, this works fine, but i also want to add the ability to have the RPi monitor a number of inputs (other GPIO pins) that are connected to basic rocker switches. these switches i would like to also be able to control the output relays. but i want to be able to override their use with the php control. (i do not need to be able to override php with the switches except to turn the output on from switch)

i cannot for the life of me work out a way to get php or python to do this - i am able to run a script continuosly on boot that can control the switch inputs to outputs but if i do so my php control stops working entirely.

and suggestions for how i can work this out?

here is one of the sections of my php script so you know for reference how i am controlling the gpios

```
    if($func=="work")
{
    if($r5==1)
        {
            system("gpio -g write 27 1");
            $_SESSION["r5"]=NULL;
            header('Location: index.php');
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Trailer Electrics Control</title>
</head>
<body background="images\VDJ.jpg">

<div align="center">

<p style="color:white">Turning Work Light OFF

<br/><br/><br/>
<a style="color:red" href="index.php">Click HERE to go back</a></p>
</div>
</body
<?php
}else{
    system("gpio -g write 27 0");
    $_SESSION["r5"]=1;
    header('Location: index.php');
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Trailer Electrics Control</title>
</head>
<body background="images\VDJ.jpg">

<div align="center">

<p style="color:white">Turning Work Light ON

<br/><br/><br/>
<a style="color:red" href="index.php">Click HERE to go back</a></p>
</div>
</body
<?php
}
}
```

i am using a RPI 2 if it makes any difference.

device will be running in a trailer with wifi connectivity once complete.

Answer (score 1):

The (Python?) script that monitors those GPIO pins most likely grabs full control of the GPIO device(s) on the RPi, so the `gpio` command line tool doesn't work.

I'd suggest making the script also accept requests over e.g. HTTP (or just a raw TCP or UDP socket, why not), so there's only one process trying to manage GPIO at a time.

Your frontend, be it PHP or whatever, can then make the request to that script. For additional simplicity, you can of course have the script itself serve your frontend HTML too.

Comment: i have not 100% decided what base language to use for the full time script as  i could use php or python, but i cannot work out how to pass requests between the scripts. also dont know how to do sockets etc in python (i have no clue whatsoever with python code - php is where most of my knowledge is but not on cli based scripts)

Comment: For simple sockets, there's a good example over at https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/socketserver.html#socketserver-tcpserver-example – for HTTP, I'd suggest the Flask or FastAPI libraries.